# How do I create the SQL for this relationship?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I get the survey sections by product id using the best method?

Also if this relationship has a name please provide it in your answer.

[image]

As requested my attempt:

```
SELECT * 
FROM survey_sections 
JOIN survey_sections_map ON survey_sections_map.survey_section_id = survey_sections.id 
JOIN product_tags_map 
WHERE product_tags_map.product_id = 2
```

second attempt...

```
SELECT * 
FROM survey_sections 
JOIN survey_sections_map ON survey_sections_map.survey_section_id = survey_sections.id 
JOIN product_tags_map ON product_tags_map.product_tag_id = survey_sections_map.product_tag_id
WHERE product_tags_map.product_id = 2
```

Comment: where's your attempt?

Comment: Closed as "product recommendation?"  What the hell.

Comment: Really? just because there's no evidence here doesn't mean I didn't try. I don't know how to handle relations in SQL when dealing with more than 3 tables.

Comment: No evidence? So, post your attempted query. Joining 3 tables is very similar to joining 2 tables.

Comment: you are clearly missing an ON statement for second join....

Comment: @MitchWheat if it was clear i wouldn't be asking the question... how is my second attempt?

Answer (score 2):

I think We can use nested select queries as well, don't know this is the best way or not but you should try it ones.

```
SELECT sur.name 
FROM survey_sections AS sur
INNER JOIN survey_sections_map AS surmap ON sur.id = surmap.survey_section_id
WHERE surmap.product_tag_id IN (SELECT product_tag_id FROM product_tags_map WHERE product_id = 2)
```